# Chosen jQuery framework select option from dropdown with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the Chosen jQuery framework with a basic select statement.

I use the following line of code to open the dropdown:

```
$('#<id-of-your-select>_chzn').trigger('mousedown');
```

That statement opens the Chosen dropdown.

[image: Chosen dropdown]

Then I want to select the top item which is a li element with the id:  pt_chzn_o_1.

I've tried the following, but none of them will select the option.

```
$('#pt_chzn_o_1').trigger('mousedown');
$('#pt_chzn_o_1').click();
```

How do you select an option using Javascript/jQuery as if I clicked the top option with my mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

The initial click triggers an event to show additional fields(optional, only needed in my specific case).

```
$("#<id-of-your-select>_chzn").trigger("click")
```

This statement opens the Chosen dropdown:

```
$("#<id-of-your-select>_chzn").trigger("mousedown")
```

Execute this statement on the li element id of the chosen dropdown element you want to choose.

```
$("#pt_chzn_o_1").trigger("mouseup")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change the selected index instead? It seems like you are trying to achieve the same thing but go about it in the "human way" as oppose to the "programming way", like so:

```
$('#<id-of-your-select>').val('value-of-pt_chzn_o_1').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Make sure to change both the jQuery selector and the value to match your circumstances.

Comment: #<id-of-your-select>_chzn is actually a <div> not a <select>.  The drop down is composed of <li> elements in a <ul> element.  I am trying to do it the "human" way because it is for automated testing and I want to closely mirror the user flow.

Comment: Gotcha, can you add your HTML to your original post? I was under the impression that this was a `select` element.

Comment: Well the way the chosen framework works is you take a select element then Chosen creates the div and hides the original select element.  The hidden select element is updated behind the scenes via the Chosen framework.

Comment: Try my edited code. The `.chosen()` function should grab the underlying select element and you should be able to operate on it like usual.

Comment: That is returning the following error for me:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Alright, one more time! Try the updated code now. You should be able to update the underlying select element directly, then notify Chosen that you have changed what is selected. Make sure the selector is the ID of the `select` element, not the Chosen `div`.